# Why am I getting zsh: command not found: README.md when running git push origin <any branch>?

Tags: git, github

I am encountering an issue when trying to push my local branch to its remote counterpart using the command `git push origin my_branch`. I am receiving the following message:

```
zsh: command not found: README.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any pre-push hooks configured? This sounds like the `README.md` (string) is being invoked like an executable - which is what will result in a command not found exception.

Comment: I am not sure about this pre-push hooks. But I am guessing that I have none. based on my directory. If this helps:

`mac@User .git % ls -a

.MERGE_MSG.swo
COMMIT_EDITMSG  
FETCH_HEAD      
ORIG_HEAD
HEAD
config
description
index
logs
packed-refs
hooks
info
objects
refs`

and the hooks directory only have the `.sample` files.

Comment: check `ls .git/hooks`